# Android Pusher not connecting to Private Channels

Tags: android, pusher

I am trying to implement pusher chat in my Android Application, i am able to connect with pusher, got the response as CONNECTED. But not able to connect to Private channels(Local server). Can anyone help on this.
adding the code below.

Thanks in advance

```
final HttpAuthorizer authorizer = new HttpAuthorizer(myurl);
    authorizer.setHeaders(getMapAuthorizationHeaders());
    PusherOptions options = new PusherOptions().setAuthorizer(authorizer);
    final Pusher pusher = new Pusher("pusher_key", options);

    pusher.connect(new com.pusher.client.connection.ConnectionEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange connectionStateChange) {

            Log.e("connectionStateChange" , connectionStateChange.getCurrentState().toString());

            if (connectionStateChange.getCurrentState() == ConnectionState.CONNECTED) {

                SOCKET_ID = pusher.getConnection().getSocketId();
                Log.e("SOCKET_ID" , ""+SOCKET_ID);


                Channel channel = pusher.subscribePrivate(PUSH_CHANNEL, new PrivateChannelEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationFailure(String s, Exception e) {
                        Log.e("PUSHER", "Channel subscription authorization failed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onSubscriptionSucceeded(String s) {
                        Log.e("PUSHER", "Channel subscription authorization succeeded");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(String s, String s2, String s3) {
                        Log.e("PUSHER", "An event with name " + s2 + " was delivered!!");
                    }
                }, "my-event");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String s, String s1, Exception e) {

        }
    });



public static HashMap<String, String> getMapAuthorizationHeaders() {
try {
    HashMap<String, String> authHeader = new HashMap<>();
    authHeader.put("HeaderKey1", "HeaderValue1");
    authHeader.put("HeaderKey2", "HeaderValue2");
    return authHeader;

} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Hello, I am facing same issue, did you get any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0):

Can I assume that where you've put `"pusher_key"`, you've just added this for security purposes on here, and in your application you're actually using your key?

Other than that, where are you defining `PUSH_CHANNEL` for: `pusher.subscribePrivate(PUSH_CHANNEL,`

Comment: i am using the original key and real_channel_name respectively

Comment: What cluster is your app in? If it's not the default one (MT1), you need to specify it.

Comment: I also getting same error..connection working fine but subscribePrivate is not calling.

Comment: hello i have the same problem, do yo revolve it?